# Converting panda object to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, import

I have a simple code to find similar rows in a dataset.

```
 h=0
count=0
#227690
deletedIndexes=np.zeros((143,))
len(data)
for i in np.arange(len(data)):
    if(data[i-1,2]==data[i,2]):
        similarIndexes[h]=int(i)
        h=h+1        
        count=count+1
        print("similar found in -->", i," there are--->", count)
```

It works correctly when data is a numpy.ndarray But if data is a panda object, i give the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "<stdin>", line 7, in smilarData
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1658, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1665, in _getitem_column
```

return self._get_item_cache(key)

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1005, in _get_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)



File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2874, in get
_, block = self._find_block(item)



File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3186, in _find_block
self._check_have(item)



 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3193, in _check_have


 raise KeyError('no item named %s' % com.pprint_thing(item))
KeyError: u'no item named (-1, 2)'
```

What should i do to use this code? If converting pandas object to numpy array is helpful, how can i do that?

Comment: You can just call `.values` on the df to get the df as a np array `df.values` will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not comment yet to Adrienne's answer so I would like to add that dataframes have built in method to convert df to array i.e. matrix

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a":range(5),"b":range(5,10)})
>>> df
   a  b
0  0  5
1  1  6
2  2  7
3  3  8
4  4  9
>>> mat = df.as_matrix()
array([[0, 5],
       [1, 6],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 8],
       [4, 9]])
>>>col = [x[0] for x in mat] # to get certain columns
>>> col
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

also to find duplicated rows you can do:

```
>>> df2
   a  b
0  0  5
1  1  6
2  2  7
3  3  8
4  4  9
5  0  5
>>> df2[df2.duplicated()]
   a  b
5  0  5
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a pandas dataframe to a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(dataFrame)
```

Answer (score 0):

I subscribe to the previous answers but in case you want to work directly with `pandas` objects, accessing DataFrame items has its own special way. In your code you should say e.g.

```
if(data.iloc[i-1,2]==data.iloc[i,2]):
```

See the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#indexing-selection) for more